# XMLHttpRequest.responseXML is NULL even when .readystate == 4

Tags: javascript, xml

I am using javascript to load in data from a XML file.  The file is not being loaded in after an if statement that checks the ready state and the status.  The ready state brings back 4 and the status brings back 200, so the last condition (the responseXML) should not be null, but for some reason, it remains null and the XML file is not loaded.

```js
function load() {
  try {
    console.log("in load");
    asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      processResponse();
    }, false);
    asyncRequest.open('GET', 'Catalog.xml', true);
    asyncRequest.send(null);
  } catch (exception) {
    alert("Request Failed");
    console.log("failed");
  }
}

function processResponse() {
  console.log(asyncRequest.readyState + " response" + asyncRequest.status + asyncRequest.responseXML);

  if (asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200 && asyncRequest.responseXML) {
    console.log("found");

    var planets = asyncRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("planet");
    var name = document.getElementById("planetinfo").value;
    console.log(name);

    for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; ++i) {

      var planet = planets.item(i);
      var planetName = planet.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;

      if (name == planetName) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = planet.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("discovered").innerHTML = planet.getElementsByTagName("discovered").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = planet.getElementsByTagName("distance").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML = planet.getElementsByTagName("contact").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='../images/" + planet.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue + "'  + '/ width = '250' height = '250'>";

      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code from the javascript file that pertains to the loading of the XML.  Opening up the console shows logs that tells me the code does not get past the if statement checking the asyncRequest.

Comment: check your **developer** tools networks tab, see if you are receiving XML

Comment: @JaromandaX I am. Status is ok (200)

Comment: yes, status is OK ... yet `.responseXML` is null - suggests you are **not** receiving (valid) XML at all - check response header content-type, and the response that is returned is actually valid XML - because clearly, the server is sending *something*, but that doesn't mean that something is *valid* XML

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I'm not understanding.  What is the response header content-type? would you like me to post my xml file as well to see if the problem is in there? When I check the networks tab, it is showing me that it is calling the actual XML file that I want it to

Comment: In developer tools network tab you can see request headers response headers and response

Comment: @JaromandaX after debugging for a long while, the problem was as simple as me declaring certain variables in the wrong order.  But solving one problem leads to discovering another, and now the program is not parsing through the XML file properly.  Thanks for the help with this question though!